# Excel VBA: Compile Error: Method or data member not found

Tags: vba, excel, compiler-errors

EDIT: To clarify, the code seen below is within a module and the UserForm is all contained within its own code.

I have the following code. When I go to run it, Excel throws me a compile error: `Method or data member not found` and highlights the following piece of code: `.showInputsDialog`. I have no idea how to resolve this error.

To give more information, the sub `sportUserForm` is supposed to call up a UserForm `sportsUsrFrm`. Any help with this issue is greatly appreciated.

```
Option Explicit

Sub sportUserForm()

Dim sSport As String, sPreference As String

If sportsUsrFrm.showInputsDialog(sSport, sPreference) Then
    MsgBox "Your favorite sport is " & sSport & ", and you usually " _
            & sPreference & "."
        Else
    MsgBox "Sorry you don't want to play."
End If
End Sub

Public Function showInputsDialog(sSports As String, sPreference As String) As Boolean
Call Initialize
Me.Show
If Not cancel Then
    If optBaseball.Value Then sSport = "Baseball"
        ElseIf optBasketball.Value Then sSport = "Basketball"
        Elss sSport = "Football"
    End If

    If optTV.Value Then sPreference = "watch on TV" _
        Else: sPreference = "go to games"
    End If

    showInputsDialog = Not cancel
    Unload Me
End Function
```

UserForm code for `sportUsrFrm`

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub cmdCnl_Click()
    Me.Hide
    cancel = True
End Sub

Private Sub cmdOK_Click()

    If Valid Then Me.Hide
    cancel = False
End Sub
```

[image: UserForm image]

Comment: What code is in what module?  Is everything in the userform?  I'd suggest taking a look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/5351/user-forms/19036/best-practices#t=201610252259347492268) in documentation for a better approach to form handling.

Comment: @Comintern I have edited the OP to reflect your questions.

Comment: Can you add the code for `sportsUsrFrm_Initialize`?

Comment: @Comintern unless that's code that has been added by default, I do not believe I have written any code for `sportsUsrFrm_Initialize`.

Comment: Is there any code in the UserForm at all?

Comment: @Comintern I've added any event handlers behind the UserForm and a picture of the UserForm itself.

Answer (score 4):

You're getting the error because `showInputsDialog` isn't a member of the form, it's a member of the module you're calling it from.  You should also be getting compiler errors on these two lines...

```
Call Initialize
Me.Show
```

...because you seem to be getting the module and form code mixed up.

That said, you're overthinking this.  A UserForm is a class module, and it can be stored in a variable (or in this case, in a `With` block), and can have properties.  I'd add a `Cancelled` property to the form:

```
'In sportsUsrFrm
Option Explicit

Private mCancel As Boolean

Public Property Get Cancelled() As Boolean
    Cancelled = mCancel
End Property

Private Sub cmdCnl_Click()
    Me.Hide
    mCancel = True
End Sub

Private Sub cmdOK_Click()
    If Valid Then Me.Hide   '<-- You still need to implement `Valid`
End Sub
```

And then call it like this:

```
Sub sportUserForm()
    With New sportsUsrFrm
        .Show
        Dim sSport As String, sPreference As String
        If Not .Cancelled Then
            If .optBaseball.Value Then
                sSport = "Baseball"
            ElseIf .optBasketball.Value Then
                sSport = "Basketball"
            Else
                sSport = "Football"
            End If

            If .optTV.Value Then
                sPreference = "watch on TV"
            Else
                sPreference = "go to games"
            End If
            MsgBox "Your favorite sport is " & sSport & ", and you usually " _
                   & sPreference & "."
        Else
            MsgBox "Sorry you don't want to play."
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```