# Excluding specified sheets when saving the .PDF version

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to hide specified sheets in my workbook, because I don't want them to be saved in my .PDF version.

Based on [How to exclude 1 sheet from my save to pdf VBA macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27283670/how-to-exclude-1-sheet-from-my-save-to-pdf-vba-macro) I specified sheet names, however I have a group of sheets, which can be expanded (Civils 1, Civils 2 exist, but the Civils 3 and so on may appear).

I prepared code:

```vb
Sub SplicingAsbuilt()
  Sheets(Array("Materials - Specifications", "Fire Stopping", "Trunking", "Drop Length Calculator", 
  "BoM", "BoQ Civils", "BoQ Cabling")).Visible = False
  If ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Name Like "*Civils*" Then
    Sheets.Visible = False
  End If
```

My console returns:

> "Method or data member not found"

An example of the answer presented here:
[Excel VBA: Compile Error: Method or data member not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40251064/excel-vba-compile-error-method-or-data-member-not-found)
doesn't apply.

[image]

Comment: IF you need to hide/unhide more than 1 worksheet, you'll need to loop trough each one of them, and based on name hide or unhide.

Comment: You need to loop through each worksheet and place your `If` statement inside the loop..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this piece of code, please:

```
Sub SplicingAsbuilt()
 Dim Sh As Worksheet, arrSh As Variant, arr As Variant
  arrSh = Array("Materials - Specifications", "Fire Stopping", "Trunking", "Drop Length Calculator", _
  "BoM", "BoQ Civils", "BoQ Cabling")

  For Each Sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    If Sh.Name Like "*Civils*" Then Sh.Visible = xlSheetHidden
    For Each arr In arrSh
       If Sh.Name = arr Then Sh.Visible = xlSheetHidden: Exit For
    Next
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: OK so in reverse sequence I should replace xlSheetHidden with xlSheetVisible right?

Comment: @Mariusz Krukar: Yes. The code is simple to be understood, I think...